# Traversing DOM with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of HTML like this:

```
<div id="contentblock">
    <div id="producttile_137" class="producttile">
        <a href="#" class="tile">
        <img src="images/Bony A-Booster.jpg" alt="Bony A-Booster - 50 ml">
            Bony A-Booster
            <span class="price">€10.95</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="producttile_138" class="producttile">
        <a href="#" class="tile">
        <img src="images/Bony B-Booster.jpg" blt="Bony B-Booster - 50 ml">
            Bony B-Booster
            <span class="price">€20.95</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>Aditional info</div>
</div>
```

I need to get all `<img />` sources but with pure Javascript. I can get element by class name `document.getElementsByClassName('producttile')` but is it possible to traversing in pure JS to `<img />` ang get `src=""` value?

Comment: Whats your problem with `document.getElementsByClassName` or `document.getElementsByTagName`? This methods are build in

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('img') should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use :

```
document.getElementsByClassName('class_name');
//OR
document.getElementsByTagName('img');
//OR
document.querySelectorAll('img');
```

All the previous methods are pure javascript and return nodes list so you could loop through them to get the `src` of every node.

Hope this helps.

Comment: As a note, the mentionned methods return HTML collections (*array-like structures*). Not being true arrays they won't have Array methods such as *forEach, reduce, map, ...*. To make use of those - very useful - methods, use the above methods, but call them with slice, such as:
`Array.prototype.slice.call(method);` then you'll have a true Array of the HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

one possible solution to get img and the src value:

```js
var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')

var res = [].slice.call(imgs).map(x=>x.getAttribute("src"))
//or in es5
//.map(function(x){return x.getAttribute("src")})
//[].slice.call is necessary to transform nodeList in array
//otherwise you can use an regular for loop

console.log(res)
```

```html
<div id="contentblock">
    <div id="producttile_137" class="producttile">
        <a href="#" class="tile">
        <img src="images/Bony A-Booster.jpg" alt="Bony A-Booster - 50 ml">
            Bony A-Booster
            <span class="price">€10.95</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="producttile_138" class="producttile">
        <a href="#" class="tile">
        <img src="images/Bony B-Booster.jpg" blt="Bony B-Booster - 50 ml">
            Bony B-Booster
            <span class="price">€20.95</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>Aditional info</div>
</div>
```

wanting to directly select an element based on it's src value you could also do this :

`document.querySelector('[src="images/Bony A-Booster.jpg"]')`

(assuming there is one element you can  use querySlector() instead of querySelectorAll() )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function getElementsByTagName.

```js
function listImages() {
  var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i in img) {
    if (img[i].src) {
      console.log(img[i].src);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="contentblock">
    <div id="producttile_137" class="producttile">
        <a href="#" class="tile">
        <img src="images/Bony A-Booster.jpg" alt="Bony A-Booster - 50 ml">
            Bony A-Booster
            <span class="price">€10.95</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="producttile_138" class="producttile">
        <a href="#" class="tile">
        <img src="images/Bony B-Booster.jpg" blt="Bony B-Booster - 50 ml">
            Bony B-Booster
            <span class="price">€20.95</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div>Aditional info</div>
</div>

<a href="#" onclick="javascript:listImages()">Show Images</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName()` to fetch all the `img` tags as a `HTMLCollection`. And then, you can iterate over the `HTMLCollection` and get the `src` attribute value by using `getAttribute()` method as below:

```js
const imgElements = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

Array.from(imgElements).forEach(function(element){
  console.log(element.getAttribute("src"));
});
```